# How to send a data response received in success function back to ajax's complete function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a code which is like this:-

```
function fetch_chat_list(post_id)
{
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>ajax-function',
    data: {'data':'chat',
         'id': post_id,
         'action': 'group'},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        var id = data.id;
        var chat = data.chat;
    },
    complete: function() 
    {
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
      setTimeout(fetch_chat_list(data.id), 25000);
    }
  });
}
```

I am getting the result response back in the success function which is `data`. It has `id` and `chat`.

Now in the complete function, I want to again call the `fetch_chat_list()` function by passsing the `data.id` which I received in the `success` function.

How can I pass data.id from `success` function to `complete` function?

Comment: Why don't you schedule the next request from the `success` function? What should happen if the Ajax request was *not* successful and there is no `data` to pass along? It seems wrong to make `complete` depend on something that is only available on success.

Comment: You can better call a custom function with `success: function(data){var id = data.id;var chat = data.chat;fnSetTimeout(chat);},` instead of try pass it from `success` to `complete`

Comment: your code will only work correctly when you have a success anyway, so put the `complete:` code at the end of `success:` and don't use `complete:`

Comment: @Saswat which version `juqery` you are using ?

Comment: You can have the complete function accept the id and call it in the success function. As others said, you could just move the setTimeout call inside the success function and not use the complete anymore. If things get messy you can extract later. But if you want to make a chat app, you should look into socket.io and have a look at web sockets. You may like it better.

Comment: @Srinu I am using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Make "id" global instead of declaring it within the success block and that should do the trick.